# Android How to print through Bluetooth printer with text alignment and also using table style?

Tags: android, text-alignment, plaintext, richtext

I am trying to print some information through bluetooth printer. I can print plain text. But I can't add any alignment and text format. Also i want to print some data like tableview.

**Text format and alignment should be like this:-**

[image]

**Table formatted data should be like this:-**

[image]

I need some **help** Please.

**Here i include my code which i try:-**

```
    String titleStr = "Title" + "\n\n";
    StringBuilder contentSb = new StringBuilder();
    contentSb.append("Item1      : 1221" + "\n");
    contentSb.append("Item2      : test" + "\n");
    StringBuilder content2Sb = new StringBuilder();
    content2Sb.append("BANK  : Us. 1.600" + "\n");
    String message  = "This is for test." + "\n\n";
    long milis      = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String date     = DateUtil.timeMilisToString(milis, "dd-MM-yy / HH:mm")  + "\n\n\n\n";

    byte[] titleByte    = titleStr.getBytes();
    byte[] content1Byte = contentSb.toString().getBytes();
    byte[] messageByte  = message.getBytes();
    byte[] content2Byte = content2Sb.toString().getBytes();
    byte[] dateByte     = date.getBytes();
    byte[] totalByte    = new byte[titleByte.length + content1Byte.length + messageByte.length +
                    content2Byte.length + dateByte.length];

    int offset = 0;
    System.arraycopy(titleByte, 0, totalByte, offset, titleByte.length);
    offset += titleByte.length;
    System.arraycopy(content1Byte, 0, totalByte, offset, content1Byte.length);
    offset += content1Byte.length;
    System.arraycopy(messageByte, 0, totalByte, offset, messageByte.length);
    offset += messageByte.length;
    System.arraycopy(content2Byte, 0, totalByte, offset, content2Byte.length);
    offset += content2Byte.length;
    System.arraycopy(dateByte, 0, totalByte, offset, dateByte.length);

    mmOutputStream.write(totalByte);
```

Comment: How is this related to iText? You talk about plain text, not about PDF. Your question doesn't contain any code. This is a very strange question.

Comment: Actually i need a solution. I can print plain text. but i can't format. If it possible to do it through pdf then i will use it. that's why i tag itext

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i include my sample code.is it possible to create pdf first and then print with format like my image through bluetooth?

Comment: I know how to create a PDF using iText and I have written thousands of examples on how to use iText, but that's not your question.